# Add Excel-Column and fill it with text

Tags: excel, vba

I got the following question. I need the code for a macro to add a column to an excel-file and fill it with a specific text. The column needs to have as many rows as in the other columns. Also it would be nice if the macro would set the datatype of the column right!

Thanks in advance! 
.penny

Comment: There are numerous questions and answers out there to answer all of you questions. You just need to break your compounded question down into several smaller questions: (1)How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro, (2) Insert New Column in Table Excel VBA, (3) Change Cell Data Type within VBA. All three questions are taken from this website. If you google them you will find the answer. Put the three things together and you should have yourself an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example.  It adds a column to an existing block of cells and fills that column:

```
Sub dural()
  Dim rng As Range, nLastColumn As Long
  Dim rng2 As Range

  Set rng = Range("D5:F15")
  nLastColumn = rng.Columns.Count + rng.Column - 1
  Set rng2 = Intersect(rng, Columns(nLastColumn)).Offset(0, 1)
  rng2.NumberFormat = "@"
  rng2.Value = "specific text"
End Sub
```